# Fast ICA to separate mixed images

Tags: matlab, image-processing, signal-processing

I'm trying to do fast ICA on a mixed signal matrix that is 4 x 400,000. (Number of components to be separated are 4).

Here is my code but I think I am confused with removing the components so that each wp is orthogonal to the other. I followed the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastICA) page on FastICA for removing multiple components.

What am I doing incorrectly? (The data is a linear mixture so I don't have to worry about linearizing the data).

```
for i = 1:1:4
    wp = rand(vectorSize,1);
    while (true) 
        wp_new = ((((wp'*XX).^3)*XX')'/numSamples) - 3*wp;
        sum_wp_new = zeros(vectorSize,1);

        % To remove contributions from previous updates
        for j = 1:1:i-1
            toMul = wp_new'*W(j,:)';
            toMul_new = toMul * W(j,:)';          
            sum_wp_new  = sum_wp_new + toMul_new;
        end
        wp_new = wp_new - sum_wp_new;

        wp_new = wp_new / norm(wp_new,2);
        check1 = norm(wp_new-wp);
        check2 = norm(wp_new + wp);
        if(check1 > epsilon) || (check2 > epsilon)  % loop should go on until wp changes
            break;
        end   
    wp = wp_new;
    end
    W(i,:) = wp';
end

S = W'*X;
```

Comment: There are good examples with the download and across the web. Which of these have you tried? Make an attempt and then come back with a  specific question. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to implement the one that was by Hyvarinen.

Comment: @chappjc The above edit explains what I did. Do you have any suggestions for my specific questions?